# Does cloud charge even after azure function is disable. Bill plan B1

Tags: azure, function

I have a azure function with bill plan as B1 and I would like to disable it. Does microsoft charge if this function is disabled.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

> I have a azure function with bill plan as B1 and I would like to
> disable it. Does microsoft charge if this function is disabled.

Yes, you will be charged for it because you're hosting your Function in an App Service Plan. Please see FAQ section: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/app-service/windows/.